# Will recordings made with Test Manager in IE8 work in IE9?

Tags: mstest, mtm, action-recording, ie9, ie8

I've had a quick read around this subject and it looks like Action Recordings can be made in Internet Explorer 9 and then played back with fast forward. However my question is about recordings made in earlier versions of Internet Explorer.

Before I upgrade to IE9 can anyone confirm for me that my Action Recordings that I made in IE8 with Test Manager will indeed work in IE9 (without having to re-record and adjust anything significantly).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at this link from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd380742.aspx).  It may answer your question in part.

In the platform support section:

> Windows Internet Explorer 9
>
> Important Windows Internet Explorer 9
>   is only supported if you have
>   installed Visual Studio 2010 Service
>   Pack 1 The following scenarios are
>   supported if you have installed Visual
>   Studio 2010 Service Pack 1:
>
> You can create an action recording or
>   coded UI test with Internet Explorer 7
>   or Internet Explorer 8 and play this
>   back using Internet Explorer 9.
>
> You can create an action recording
>   using Internet Explorer 9 running in
>   compatibility mode and play this back
>   with Internet Explorer 7, Internet
>   Explorer 8 or Internet Explorer 9.
>
> You can create a coded UI test from an
>   action recording or by recording
>   actions using Internet Explorer 9
>   running in compatibility mode. You can
>   run this test with Internet Explorer
>   7, Internet Explorer 8 or Internet
>   Explorer 9.
>
> Important You cannot create an action
>   recording using the standard mode for
>   Internet Explorer 9 because the new
>   features and controls for Internet
>   Explorer 9 are not currently
>   supported.

Comment: Thanks I had been reading around the MSDN but didn't stumble across this page. Nice one :)